# Continuously Combining local file with files downloaded from S3

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow where I am fetching files from `S3`. A pair of files are fetched through `S3` and later passed into a `MergeContent` processor. Next, there is a `README` file that needs to go with each pair of files.

This `README` file is always same and I have stored it locally. I have a `ExecuteStreamCommand` that takes in content from the `MergeContent` processor.

I have tried passing in the `README` file into the `MergeContent` processor using the `ListFile`/`FetchFile` combination but its not working as expected. I guess the final result that I am looking for is a `MergeContent` package that contains a pair of files downloaded from `S3` + the `README` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you will want to use `GetFile` for the `README` -- the path is static, and you can set the `Keep Source File` setting to `true` in order to constantly retrieve the same content.

`ListFile`/`FetchFile` probably isn't working because once `ListFile` retrieves a filename from the directory, it stores the timestamp in its local state and won't retrieve files older than that on the next execution.